# Calculate mouse position after camera translation and zoom

Tags: camera, libgdx, 2d

Been grappling with a working formula for hours now...

I'm rendering a 2D top down world using the Libgdx camera class. The camera is moved around on the x and y axes and zoomed in and out with its zoom parameter.

I want to be able to click accurately on the world no matter what the camera's position and zoom is. So even when WorldPoint(50, 70) translates to ScreenPoint(50, 90) when I translate the camera by (0, 20) and keep zoom at 1, I still want to be able to click on ScreenPoint(50, 90) and get back WorldPoint(50, 70). You know what I mean?

This is my function so far...

```
Vector2 adjustedMouseInput(float screenX, float screenY) 
{
    screenX += (cam.position.x * cam.zoom) - (screenWidth/2);
    screenY += (cam.position.y * cam.zoom) - (screenHeight/2);

    screenX *= cam.zoom;
    screenY *= cam.zoom;

    return new Vector2(screenX, screenY);
}
```

I got that far mostly through trial error and it doesn't work but I feel like some of it is half-right, you know? I've tried every permutation of zooms * positions and screenWidths / Sqrt(pi) so I'm getting sick of it and need someone who's done this before to just tell me what the proper formula is.

The zoom parameter zooms out when it gets higher, the camera position defaults to center of the screen, hence the -screenwidth/2... And I think that's all that needs to be known

Comment: `camera.unproject(screenPos)`

Comment: a bittersweet ending... thank you!